# How to install and run Evince from tar.gz

Tags: gnome, gtk, evince

I am trying to build Evince so that I can alter slightly (without needing new dependencies).

I don't want it to run in a sandbox; I want it to run with other applications on my system (I had a pretty bad time with JHBuild anyways).

I download the tar.gz and extract it in the Download folder.

I run `./configure`, and install all the missing packages

Then I run `make` and then `make install`

Then in `/usr/local/bin`, I try running `./evince`, but this error is returned:

```
symbol lookup error: ./evince: undefined symbol: ev_view_set_enable_spellchecking
```

which is function in Evince. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have gspell installed in version >= 1.6.0.

Source: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/commit/719f7dccdb34f45caf6214ed45fd22fdad158c8a

Alternatively, if you don't care about this feature, try `./configure --without-gspell` and then make && make install.

I also strongly suggest you to use a packaging system from your distribution to prepare a package instead of installing binaries directly into the system. Firstly, you avoid the mess in the filesystem, secondly your distribution most likely provides some paches or configuration options which already handle this problem.

Comment: When I first run configure, an error was retruned about gspell-1 not being found. I installed libgspell-1-dev, after which the configure could complete. I could live without the feature, but why is it not recognizing the package?

Comment: No idea. Which version of this library you have?

Comment: +1. Disabling gspell did not help in my case, still the same `undefined symbol` for evince 3.35.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about the same library? To help you fix the problem, please use ldd /usr/local/bin/evince and strace envince.
https://linoxide.com/linux-command/ldd-command-examples-linux/
https://www.tecmint.com/strace-commands-for-troubleshooting-and-debugging-linux/