# How do I upgrade Evince?

Tags: ubuntu, evince

I'm desperately looking for the integration of keyboard shortcuts to add notes and highlighting to PDF documents in Evince on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. This feature comes with evince 3.31.0 but Ubuntu 18.04 ships 3.28.4.

What I tried so far:

- Installed `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` repository and tried to upgrade from there as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310974/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-evince). The package manager insists that I already have the newest version.
- Install the newest version of evince from source. Configuring, making and installing works fine, but

```
evince: symbol lookup error: evince: undefined symbol: ev_view_set_enable_spellchecking
```

- install *exactly* the version that ships the feature, 3.31.0, from source, same issue as above.
- try the previous, but disable spell checks upon configuring with `--without-gspell` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564110/how-to-install-and-run-evince-from-tar-gz), but the error is the same.

Any help would be appreciated since I (1) do not like other pdf viewers and (2) need the feature for commenting on publications. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [evince 3.34.2](https://snapcraft.io/evince) snap app.

[How to install Evince on Ubuntu](https://snapcraft.io/install/evince/ubuntu#install)

1. Install snapd (not needed for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) or later, you can skip this step):

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install snapd
   ```
2. Install evince:

   ```
   sudo snap install evince
   ```

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of snap.

Comment: and how do i use latest version, because when i do evince --version it is still showing 3.28.4?

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the version of evince that comes preinstalled.

```
sudo apt-get -y remove evince
```

Then install via `snap`

```
sudo snap install evince
```